# Vertical and Horizontal Recyclerview in the same layout

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I see a lot of apps using this layout but i never understand how to create something like this:

[Recyclerview Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iE5O.jpg)

What i have to do?

- Create 3 recyclerview inside the same layout
- Use a main recyclerview and in adapter "inflate" the Horizontal and Vertical
- Something else?

I don't know if it's possible inflate different recyclerview(horizontal and vertical) in the same Adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's called a nested recycler view. you basically have a vertical recycler view in which you inflate your child recycler views and inside the child recycler views you inflate your final CardViews.

[Here is a tutorial](https://android.jlelse.eu/easily-adding-nested-recycler-view-in-android-a7e9f7f04047)